# jQuery Remove table row on $.ajax success

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I need to remove a table row after a successful ajax call, not sure how to do it. Here is my code:

```
function closelead(rowid){
            var rowid1 = rowid;
            alert(rowid1);
            var parent = $(this).parent();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax/close.php",
                data: "rowid="+ rowid1,

                success: function(html){


                }
            });

            }
```

```
<tr><td><input type="button" onclick="closelead(<?php echo $leadlist['ID'];?>)" value="Close" class="searchbutton" /></td></tr>
```

Comment: your javascript and html looks solid (Sean's answer has a nice structure though).  your problem may be something else entirely; on the success function, put a line to `alert(html);`.  also add an `error: function(html) { alert(html); }` also.

Comment: @rkw it returns the echo from the php "true". its completing the mysql query on the back end but its not executing $(this).closest('tr').remove();

Comment: append `return false;` to your `onclick` statement; to prevent any postback that may occur.  inside your `success` function, use the code from Adil.  If that doesn't work, instead of the code from Adil, put in `console.log($(this).closest('tr'))` and see what object the console returns

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**closest()**](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to find out the row containing the clicked button and use [**remove()**](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) to remove the row of button.

```
success: function(html){
       $(this).closest('tr').remove();
}
```

Comment: This is what i tried, not working from some reason. The PHP is modifying the row as its supposed to but this is not removing the row. Any suggestions?

Comment: What php do with this row? try debugging the code to find out the reason.

Comment: It adds 1 year to the wcxdate, returns success

Comment: How you use html returned by success ?

Comment: Dont quite understand the question? what does my php return?

Comment: I was trying to make sure if you changing the DOM in success as you have a parameter html in success method, If you are modifying/rebuilding the html containing button being clicked then remove could fail otherwise it should work.

Answer (score 2):

Onclick is so 1999...

```
$('#closelead').on('click', function() {
    var $row = $(this).parent().parent();
    var rowid = $(this).data("row-id");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax/close.php",
        data: "rowid=" + rowid,
        success: function() {
            $row.remove();
        }
    });
});​
```

Change HTML to this.

```
<tr><td><button id="closelead" class="searchbutton" data-row-id="<?php echo $leadlist['ID'];?>">Close</button></td></tr>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JrWBh/1/)

Comment: what if savagenoob wants HTML Strict then custom attribute may come in way.

Comment: HTML5 is the future =p, also it just throws off the validators it doesn't change any of functionality.  Also jQuery supports data attributes out of the box now.

Answer (score 1):

Look in your code you already have `var parent = $(this).parent();` declared.
Now after successful ajax response use `parent.parent().remove();`
This would be easy and understandable too.

Answer (score 0):

use `remove().`

```
$(this).closest('tr').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Jquery [remove](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)  - it will do the trick